# How to add a second hosted domain in place of a currently hosted subdomain on Bluehost?

Tags: domains, redirects, subdomain, nameserver

I have two domains, `dom0.example` and `dom1.example`. The nameservers of `dom0.example` are set to my webhosting on Bluehost.

Now I have a second website under `sub.dom0.example`. I want `dom1.example` to pointing to `sub.dom0.example` (on the same webhosting but in a subfolder), but with keeping `dom1.example` as the URL. Also, I would like that `sub.dom0.example` redirects to `dom1.example`, such that I don't see the subdomain in the URL.

My webhoster is bluehost and it's a shared hosting. It has its own management system and a cPanel section for "advanced" options, yet the cPanel is missing some options which I've seen in other ones, such as the domain part. My hosted offers add-on domains in the domain section of the general management system, but not for the basic plan (which I have).
I had a same situation some years ago (same hoster) and I could solve it without opting for the more expensive plan, but I can not figure out how I did it back then.

Comment: Have you tried using CNAME records in DNS?  Set one up with dom1.example CNAME => sub.dom0.example

Comment: You could potentially solve this by configuring a reverse proxy - but this wouldn't necessarily be possible on a shared host, as you really need access to the server config to set this up properly. (?)